# All applications disappeared but they are still running

Tags: windows-11

My baby touched the screen of my laptop (with touch-screen), and suddenly all open windows disappeared.

I can still see them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but even when I switch to them, I do not see the window. I also tried to click <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to check for alternative desktops, but I have only one desktop.

How can I restore my application windows?

Comment: My first suggestion, reboot the system, and clarify your question because what you described is different to envision without a screenshot

Comment: Did you try restarting explorer.exe process to eliminate glitching type of issues? Note that it will close any running windows related to Windows Explorer.

Comment: Shutdown the computer, turn off the screen, and restart.

Comment: @harrymc this works, but I am looking for a milder solution, that does not require a complete restart.

Comment: Keep the baby away from the screen ?

Comment: @Destroy666 this looks like a good solution - I will try this next time.

Comment: They've probably switched to a different workspace or Task View Desktop. Look for the Task View icon in your Task Bar near to the Start Menu and Search bar and open that. Look to see if there's a desktop showing there that you can switch to that has your program windows running. This could also be a case of the computer thinking it is connect to a secondary screen, and all the running program windows are on that.

Answer (score 0):

You might *try* hibernating by

- Pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, typing `powercfg -h on` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Then pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, typing `shutdown /h` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Then pressing power key to resume, in the hope that the work open on the desktop would not be lost.

If that doesn't help, then

- Using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, go into each application for which you wish to save data.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, used by *most* applications to save the current work. Though you can't see the app, hopefully, data *will* be saved.
- Reboot.